# Manage.py is added to PYTHONPATH, but can't be found

Tags: python, pythonpath

In my, apparently faulty, understanding of PYTHONPATH, calling `sys.path` returns the contents of PYTHONPATH. Using the windows GUI, I added a script -manage.py, from Django- to it.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\programming\\django_testing\\tango_with_django_project\\manage.py', 'C:\\Users\\mjpvanzuijlen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36', ]
```

I though this would allow me to call it in CMD from whatever directory using:

```
 C:\>python manage.py
```

Yet, this returns an error:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Clearly my understanding of PYTHONPATH is wrong. How would I be able to call a file, in this case `manage.py`  from any location in CMD?

*EDIT:* 
I changed the path from `.../manage.py` to the directory. It still returns the same error.

```
 >>> import sys
 >>> sys.path
 ['', 'C:\\programming\\django_testing\\tango_with_django_project',
```

Comment: For this to work `manage.py` has to be in the folder you run this from.

Comment: @KlausD. It is.  Direct copy from `manage.py properties` reveal it to be in `C:\\programming\\django_testing\\tango_with_django_project`

Comment: And you are in the folder `C:\programming\django_testing\tango_with_django_project` when running it? Your prompt says you are not.

Comment: @KlausD. I see I understood your first comment wrong. No, I'm trying to run it from `C:`. If I `CD` to the folder that holds `manage.py` it works. But, what I wish is to be able to call `manage.py` from any folder. I though that is what PYTHONPATH enables?

Comment: You can not open a Python file like that. The PYTHONPATH is only applied to imports not when opening a Python file. There is the `-m <module>` argument that might be able to do what you want: `python -m manage`. This requires `manage.py` to be importable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I be able to call [..] manage.py from any location in CMD?

You can't. `manage.py` needs to be called from the directory where it's located. It wouldn't make sense otherwise, as a`manage.py` files exist for each django project, which would easily go wrong.

This is also true in the general case: You can't call a .py file from outside the directory. Only modules can be called this way.

Information mostly from Klaus D. in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Add the directory to PYTHONPATH instead of the file:

```
'C:\\programming\\django_testing\\tango_with_django_project'
```

Python will then look for `'manage.py'` inside that directory.

Comment: That makes sense, but it still says it can not be found.